# Extract Zip files in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to extract zip files from s3 bucket and writing files back to another s3 bucket.Currently I have zip file size of 150 GB in s3 Bucket.

When I execute the below code, its keep on running from several hours and there is no output.Is there any alternative way to improve performance ? I appreciate your response.

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name="bucket_name_here", key=zip_key)
buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())
z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
for filename in z.namelist():
    file_info = z.getinfo(filename)
    s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
      z.open(filename),
       Bucket=bucket,
      Key=f'{filename}'
     )
```

Comment: Where do you run this code? On EC2 or local?  Which instance type? (What is decompressed size?) Do you use S3 private link?

Comment: This will require you to download entire 150GB object first, before you can unzip it. This can take time.

Comment: As mentioned, this requires you to download the entire 150gb.  You're downloading it to memory, and doing so with a single thread, so it will take time.  And, even when that's done, you're not outputting any status, so the upload will take time to complete as well.

Comment: I am running code on EC2